# Why hasn't my Launchpad karma changed in nearly a week?

Tags: launchpad

My Launchpad karma has neither increased nor decreased in many days now, despite my being active on the site in that time. I've checked the Launchpad blog and there's no mention of any ongoing maintenance that would affect the functionality of the site.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It updated itself earlier today with a weeks worth of karma. I don't know what the issue was but it appears to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your Launchpad [actions history](https://launchpad.net/~notgary/+karma), all your actions this week happened less that 24 hours ago, perhaps Launchpad has not yet done its [daily karma calculation](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/Karma):

> Then, **once a day**, Launchpad looks at all of the work you've done and gives each action a score. The score it gives depends on:
>
> - what sort of work you did - e.g. work on blueprints may result in more karma than some other types of work
> - when you did the work.

(Emphasis mine).

Comment: The action history only lists a certain number of items, and it's possible to fill out the list only with items carried out in the past hour, which I've done in the past. I've done a lot on the site over the past week which I would have expected to have accumulated some karma by now.